# working with views in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am joining total 4 tables and creating a view.

The details of the tables are as below,

```
System:
Integer SystemId;
String Systemvalue;

Client:
Integer ClientId;
String login_username

ClientSystem:
Integer ClientSystemId;
Integer SystemId;

Login:
String login_username;
```

Joining the above 4 tables(left join and right join) I created a view. The view is not meant to identify any row identically (it is not having any primary key), as this query consists of left and right joins, some of the columns will be null.

But hibernate expects primary key for each table.

I tried the following ways:

1. Made composite primary key, considering each column of the view.
2. Tried for sequence

By following 1st approach the issue I faced is, whenever I tried querying I used to get the number of tuples equal to the number of tuples which would be returned when I run the query manually in the workbench, but all the objects would be null.

I thought of trying the 2nd approach, but after googling came to know that mysql does not support sequence, hence only way left to me is to write stored procedure to generate unique number for each tuple.

Please let me know which approach to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined LoginUsername and SystemId (if not null if null then made it 0) so that it would be the primary key for the view.

The issue is solved now.